# Why doesn't this array and foreach work with mysqli?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I got this code

```
$a = "I love Steve Jobs.";

$targets = array('bill gates','steve jobs');
foreach($targets as $t)
{
   if (preg_match_all("/\b" . $t . "\b/i", $a)) {
    $b[] = $t;
   }
}
```

This code finds ALL matches in the array, which is great

Now I got a database with a table called "tags" - in here there is around 500 keywords. I wan't to make this work together with the script above.

All I have to do in my logic, is to make an array which replaces `$targets`.

This code I made right here, does not work:

```
$result = $con->query("SELECT tag FROM tags");
$targets = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach($targets as $t)
{
   if (preg_match_all("/\b" . $t . "\b/i", $a)) {
    $b[] = $t;
   }
}
```

I get this notice:

> **Notice**: Array to string conversion

I don't know what to do - 2 hours passed by and I can't figure it out.

Thank you :)

Comment: in second code replace `$t` with `$t['tag']`

Comment: @Lashane I'm getting the same notice. It made no difference.

Comment: add `var_dump($t);` to loop

Comment: @Lashane - since you were the one fixing the problem . can you give me an answer?

Comment: no need to duplicate answers to such questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### in your code, you have:

```
if (preg_match_all("/\b" . $t . "\b/i", $a)) {
```

but `$t` is row in array, that is array with key `tag`.

you should have:

```
if (preg_match_all("/\b" . $t['tag'] . "\b/i", $a)) {
```

#### Same in other line, should be:

```
$b[] = $t['tag'];
```

#### summary

[`fetch_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) return array of arrays that hold row from database.

You can always check value with methods [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) or [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)

Answer (score 1):

[mysqli_fetch_all/mysqli_result::fetch_all](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) returns an array of arrays representing result rows. In your example it would return a structure like this:

```
array(
    array('tag' => 'bill gates'),
    array('tag' => 'steve jobs')
)
```

You should be using `$t['tag']` instead of `$t` inside the loop.

By the way, the easiest way to quickly debug situations like these, you can output the query results (or any other variable) with [print_r()](http://php.net/print_r) or [var_dump()](http://php.net/var_dump), and see how they're structured.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

You can try use this code:
mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)

Comment: This only returns one row of results. He wants to test against all the results of the query.